# Pass null String to Web API 2 (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Test> GetTest(Int32 idTest, String codTest, Int value)
```

and a test client like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
response = await client.GetAsync("Test/GetTest/0/null/1/");
```

I need to pass null in the second parameter (that is not optional), but on server side I get a string with "null" inside and not the null value. I would not to put conversion functions for each parameter. I see that works if I put [FromBody] attribute to just one parameter, but if I set [FromBody] for all the string parameters I get internal server error.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You typically shouldn't have optional parameters in the middle of a route.

I would recommend changing the order of your parameters, or add them as query parameters so they can be optional.

e.g.  for http://example.com/Test/GetTest?a=0&b=&c=1

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetTest(Int32 idTest)
{
    var queryPairs = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
    DoSomething(queryPairs);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I know, but I need to pass optional parameters in the middle because my APIs are wrapper of another library. Thanks.